# convert an image to value (hex code for example) with opencv and python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, encoding

I'm currently working on image processing, and I want to convert some images to a code (hexadecimal for example).
I'm using opencv with python.

Here is the code I'm using, but it's not working.

```
import cv2
import base64
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
imcode = base64.b64encode(buffer)
print(imcode)
```

and the response is "must be string or buffer, not tuple"

Comment: check the code to see which line returns a tuple instead of single output. i'm not sure which one but if you debug or print the `image` or `buffer` you will see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function imencode return a tuple:

> Python: cv2.imencode(ext, img[, params]) → retval, buf
>   https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html

This is where your error come from.

You can try with:

```
(tmp,buffer) = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
```